# Timeout for long running 3rd library method

Tags: c#

I want to add ability to cancel long running external method (in code below is it `LongOperation` method from `SomeExternalClass` class), so I wrap this method into task and add custom task extension for handle timeout.

TimeoutException is successful throwed after specific period of time, but external method is **not** canceled. How I can cancel `LongOperation`?

```
class Program
{
    private static CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource;

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        cancellationTokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        try
        {
            await SearchTask().WithTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
        }
        catch (TimeoutException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Timeout");
            cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Program end");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static Task SearchTask()
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start task");

            SomeExternalClass.LongOperation();

            Console.WriteLine("End task");
        }, cancellationTokenSource.Token);
    }
}

public static class SomeExternalClass
{
    // this is simulation of long running 3rd party method 
    public static void LongOperation()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start LongOperation");
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        Console.WriteLine("End LongOperation");
    }
}

public static class TaskExtension
{
    public static async Task WithTimeout(this Task task, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        if (task == await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(timeout)))
        {
            await task;
        }
        throw new TimeoutException();
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Start task
Start LongOperation
Timeout
Program end
End LongOperation
End task
```

Comment: If the external operation does not support cancellation (maybe an overload?) then you are already pretty close to what you can do. You may try to [interrupt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.interrupt(v=vs.110).aspx) the thread but then the operation has to support interrupts. Do you have control over that external class's code?

Comment: @Fildor no, I don't have control over that external code

Comment: Is timeout an exceptional case or a normal one? There is [Thread.Abort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty8d3wta(v=vs.110).aspx) in case you want to deal with frozen peace of someone else code, but that has no guarantees to abort anything or a normal work afterwards. Could be useful as a last resort before exiting application.

Comment: @Sinatr is it exceptional case, but it shouldn't stop normal work